# Connecting Java and Chrome extension via native messaging

Tags: java, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to connect Chrome extension to Java application on MacOS. Using manifest version 2 for testing purposes. My question is this - what should I specify as path inside host manifest file?

`host_manifest`

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "path": "...", <---- talking about this
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://.../"
    ]   
}
```

Since Java is not a native application I think I should specify something like bash file that runs jar file with Java.

`start.bash`

```
java -jar "native-messaging-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
```

Then I specify like this

`host_manifest`

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "path": "/bunch/of/directories/start.bash", <---- changed to location of start.bash
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://.../"
    ]   
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work saying: `Failed to start native messaging host.`. I think my mistake is made here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.sh` extension for the Bash file. Make sure the `.sh` file is executable and write the absolute path to the `.sh` file in `"path"` value in the manifest.